# How to store rich text data?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rich-text-editor

I'm developing a blog app. Currently, when posting a blog entry, you can upload plain text and no more than one image per post.

I want to add a rich text (WYSIWYG) editor. How can I persist and retrieve the rich text formatting (style, font, color etc) to and from the firebase database?

Also, how can I add the capacity to store an arbitrary number of images?

Comment: Which format does the editor generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the documents they have following methods to get the contents and render

```
render(); //Render the editor. This method must be called to render the editor.
render(String html); //Render the editor with HTML as parameter.
render(EditorState state); //Render the editor with the state as a parameter

getContent(); //returns the content in the editor as EditorState
getContentAsSerialized(); //returns the content as serialized form of EditorState
getContentAsSerialized(EditorState state); //returns the provided parameter as serialized.
getContentAsHTML(); //returns the editor content in HTML format.
```

So you can use `getContent()` as per your requirement and directly store the content and use render method while displaying.

You can search how to store Serialised Objects inside Firebase to store `EditorState` object or directly store HTML text as `String`.